# writing to sdcard not working

Tags: android-emulator

I am running Android in Eclipse. the following line (from Camera.demo)

```
outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", 
    System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

fails and returns the following error:-

```
FileNotFound - permission denied.
```

Is there anything I can do to correct this?    I have assumed that the sdcard directory is present in the emulator.
Thanks
Ron

Answer (score 1):

The AVD you're running has to be explicitly configured with SD card support or it will behave as if there isn't one.  More information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html).

Your application also needs the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Side note:  You should be calling `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the SD card's path instead of hard-coding `/sdcard`.  It returns `null` if there's no storage available.  You can use the `canWrite()` method on the returned value to determine if it's actually something you can use for storage.

Comment: Thanks - that has fixed it.  I appreciate the help.