# Running a shell command to copy files from Android App

Tags: android, shell, process, command, root

i'm trying to get an app started so I can backup my apps to sdcard. I ran:

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    Process c = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "cp /data/app/com.ebay.mobile-1.apk"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/ebay.apk");
    Log.d("copy", "done");
```

When it runs I can grant super user then it says it's done but there is no file is not copied. I'm just using the eBay app as an example and test.

Thanks for any help.

Fix: thanks for the help below but i found a full fix and kinda different way of doing things here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735273/copy-folders-in-data-data-to-sdcard-viceversa?rq=1"

Comment: Wow, do I feel like an idiot, I hadn't added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Got it all working now with "dd if=source_file of=dest_file"

Comment: the solution which found by yourself worked, thanks for shares!

Answer (score 7):

Android doesn't support `cp` command. For this you have to either use **cat** command (**from shell only**)like,

```
cat source_file > dest_file
```

Or use **BusyBox** with your application.

**EDIT:**

also you can use command,

```
dd if=source_file of=dest_file
```

Comment: More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714411/how-to-copy-and-edit-files-in-android-shell

Comment: Note you don't actually need root, provided the application has the external storage permission.  But cat source > dest trick is not a process you can execute, but rather something that has to be interpreted by a shell.  It would be probably be preferable to read the file and write it back out using a while loop in java.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - If you want to install busybox and use command shell then only need root permission, else other options works with only WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in application's manifest file.

Comment: I've tried both your suggestions but couldn't get them to work, there no errors and it says its done but nothing actually happened. Do you have any examples?

Comment: @ChrisStratton - cat command works because the phone has a full-featured shell which supports stream redirection.

Comment: @user370305 No, you do not need root to install busybox; you only need root to install it in particular places.  The cat command **WILL NOT WORK** for this usage, because no shell is being invoked by the asker's program.  They would have to exec the shell instead, and pass the compound command to it.

Comment: @user1056798 - Did you mentioned "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in application's manifest file.

Comment: @user1056798 If you do a search you will find many examples on how to copy a file with java.

Comment: @user370305 From a **shell** yes, but the asker is not running a shell.  Try the posted code snippet with your 'cat source_file > dest_file' - it will not work, as there is no shell to interpret the meaning of '>'

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Yes, you are right, As In my answer I just give a alternative to CP command, but I forgot to mentioned its for shell. Anyway I edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This QA helped me out a lot, so I wanted to add something to the various exec answers.  Rather than using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String), consider using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[]).  This should prevent file paths with spaces from wreaking havoc on your filesystem.

Try

```
Process copy = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
new String[]{
    "dd", 
    "if=" + inputFile.getAbsolutePath(), 
    "of=" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath()
});
```